# How to display a MySQL Many to Many Relationship with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display information on a website using PHP and MYSQL that shows all the locations an event can take place, along with the facilities each location includes. For example, a park (location1) may contain toilets (facility1), swings (facility3) and a slide (facility4).

```
              Location1    Location2    Location3    Location4
Facility1         x            x
Facility2                                   x            x
Facility3         x                                      x
Facility4         x            x
```

Firstly, I am unsure of the best way to display these as tables in MySQL and then how I would display this clearly using PHP calls onto a webpage.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: in MySQL most likely three tables  `Location`, `Facility`, `Location_has_Facility` .. Location where the store the location `(park)`. Facility where you store the Facility `(toilets, swings, slide)` and Location_has_Facility where you store if a Location `(park)` has a Facility `(toilets, swings, slide)`..

Comment: Thank you! From this, what MySQL query would I use to show the locations that have toilets AND swings AND slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Database schema

I would like to recommend you to create 3 tables in your database:

1. locations
2. facilities
3. location_facility

**Locations table**

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | location_1 |
|  2 | location_2 |
+----+------------+
```

**Facilities table**

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | facility_1 |
|  2 | facility_2 |
|  3 | facility_3 |
+----+------------+
```

**Pivot table (location_facility)**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| location_id | facility_id |
+-------------+-------------+
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           2 |
|           2 |           1 |
|           2 |           3 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

So, in pivot table you can store required information.

## PHP application meta code

To get the data from your database in pure PHP - you can use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) extension.

```
    $sql = 'SELECT locations.name as loc_name, 
                   facilities.name as facility_name 
            FROM location_facility
            INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = location_facility.location_id
            INNER JOIN facilities ON facilities.id = location_facility.facility_id';

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['loc_name'] . "\t";
        print $row['facility_name'] . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: This was really helpful and shows all the locations and facilities, thank you! Is there a way to narrow down this search so it does not repeat locations. For example, if I were to query for locations with a toilet and a swing? I tried using WHERE facility.name LIKE '%Toilet%' AND facility.name LIKE '%Swing%' but this did not work.

Comment: Sadly, I don't believe it is a typo error. I believe the issue is that the WHERE clause shows only rows with 'Toilet' as a facility name, so then, attempting to search for facilities named swing results in 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

In the database it is only one additional table, holding both PK from the related tables.

For display you'd choose a "master-detail" view: seleting one item from either table (master), showing all related records from the other (detail).

Answer (score 0):

As others had commented, the tables required a third pivot table to connect the facilities and the location tables so many thanks for that. However, the next issue that arose was using these tables and connecting them to allow searches by facilities. 
Hence an SQL query that grouped the facilities into one column within a view alongside all information from the location table.

```
CREATE VIEW locations AS
SELECT location.*, group_concat(facilities.FacilityName separator ',') AS facility_name 
FROM location_facility 
INNER JOIN location 
ON location.LocationID = location_facility.LocationID
INNER JOIN facilities 
ON facilities.FacilitiesID = location_facility.FacilitiesID
GROUP BY location.LocationName  
ORDER BY location.LocationID ASC
```

[image: Created view showing grouped facilities]

This table can be queried using

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE facility_name LIKE %Toilet% AND facility_name LIKE %Parking%
```

This solved my issues and allowed the data to be displayed on a webpage exactly how I had desired.

Thanks again for the comments and help all!